# Turning an SVG strip into a 3d flat ring

Tags: three.js

I am trying to take an SVG rectangular shape and bend it into a 3d ring.
I've successfully created a 3d shape by extruding an SVG shape with Three.js, now I want to take this shape and bend it into a ring.

I really have no idea where to start so any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that with the [Mod3 library](https://github.com/foo123/MOD3) (it's Bend modifier in particular) and the three.js plugin it comes with. Be sure to check our the three.js example the library comes with.

Off the top of my head, you can try this after importing the Mod3 library:

```
var mstack = new MOD3.ModifierStack( MOD3.LibraryThree, YOUR_MESH_HERE ).worker( true );

var bend = new MOD3.Bend( );
bend.offset = 0.5;
bend.setAngle(Math.PI * 2);
bend.force = 4;

mstack.addModifier( bend );
mstack.apply();
```

I'm not sure the angle and force values are 100% correct for your flat ring, but perhaps it will help you tweak values and find the right one for your mesh.